# How and why do servers use random port numbers?

Tags: tcp, udp, port

Well-known services usually use a pre-defined port number on the server-side.

However, I realized that that is not always the case. Some services and games for example seem to pick a random port from a pre-defined range.

when you connect to a pre-defined port number, you send a request first, so the client's port can be determined, but if the service's port is not predetermined, how does the client know to which port to send the request? Also, what is the reason for always using a different port and how does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does the client know to which port to send the request?

This depends on the specific protocol. For example with protocols like SIP, H.323 or FTP there are predefined port numbers for the signaling channel. The actual data transfer though is done by new connections on dynamic ports. These ports are advertised within the signaling channel.

In other cases there is no such signaling channel on a predefined port number. This is typically the case for servers which have no IANA assigned port number. It also happens when multiple instances (with different configurations) of the server should run on the same system and these simply cannot use the same port number.  In this case the relevant IP and port might be advertised for example through [DNS SRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) records. And of course there might be other ways, like publishing the information on some web site or similar.

> Also, what is the reason for always using a different port ...

Again it depends on the specific protocol. With SIP, H.323 or FTP for example the data connection is specific to the client and it will simply use a port which is free on the system for this. And there can be multiple connections at the same time from the same or from different clients which all use different ports. Any restrictions regarding the range of the port are usually only done to work better with firewalls, so that these don't need to open a huge port range but can allow a smaller port range and thus lower the attack surface.

> ... and how does this happen?

Just let the system pick a random port by not giving a specific value. Or if a port should be used from a range then it will simply figure out which port is available by trying to bind to the port and continue with the next if the binding failed.

Answer (score 1):

> if the service's port is not predetermined, how does the client know to which port to send the request?

The port has to be known ahead of time, entered by the user, or advertised somewhere the client can find it.

> what is the reason for always using a different port

Many reasons: security, network/firewall restrictions, etc.